# How to remove subviews from UITabbarcontroller view using objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I added UILabel object to the tab bar controller view in a method using `For` Loop, but in another method I need to remove all UILabel sub views from tabbarcontroller view.

**Here is my code for adding:**

```
-(void)tabBarImage_methodAdding:(NSNotification *)note
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        UILabel *objLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18+80*i,            
                                      screenRect.size.height-18, 70, 15)];
        objLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        objLabel.text=[tabBarNamesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        objLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];
        objLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:objLabel];
        [objLabel release];objLabel=nil;
    }
}
```

**Here is my code for removing:**

```
-(void)tabBarImage_methodRemoving:(NSNotification *)note
{
    for (UILabel *lab in self.tabBarController.view)
    {
        [lab removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: If any answer had helped you, then you should accept it. You have not accepted any answer yet, there are many answers those are really good & correct for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for (id subview in self.tabBarController.view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(self.tabBarController!=nil){
    while ([self.tabBarController.subviews count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"subviews Count=%d",[[self.tabBarController subviews]count]);
        [[[self.tabBarController subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tabBarImage_methodRemoving:(NSNotification *)note
{
    for (id obj in self.tabBarController.view.subviews)
    {
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
         [obj removeFromSuperview];   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your `For` loop:-
`[self.tabBarController.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];`

Answer (score -1):

When you are adding UILabels to the tabbarcontroller view take help of tag.i.e

```
   - (void)tabBarImage_methodAdding:(NSNotification *)note
    {
       CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
       for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
       {
          UILabel *objLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18+80*i,            
                                      screenRect.size.height-18, 70, 15)];
          objLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
          objLabel.text=[tabBarNamesArray objectAtIndex:i];
          [objLabel setTag:1000+i];
          objLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];
          objLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
          [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:objLabel];
          [objLabel release];objLabel=nil;
      }

  - (void)tabBarImage_methodRemoving:(NSNotification *)note
   {
       for (UIView *lab in self.tabBarController.view.subviews)
       {
       if(lab.tag>=1000 && lab.tag<1004)
          [lab removeFromSuperview];
       }
   }
```